# Cómo asociar cada imagen a un nuevo activity usando Gridview

Tags: android, gridview

hola a todos mi duda es cómo puedo asociar una imagen a su respectivo activity al momento de dar click sobre la imagen usando Gridview ya que debo hacer un pequeño albúm de fotos de animales para que cuando de click abra otro Activty con detalles más especificos del animal, ¿se puede hacer o convendría usar otro método? 
Gracias
Este sería mi código en mi MainActivity

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}
```

}
`

Y este otro en otra clase utilizando imageAdapter

```
class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(240, 240));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;

}
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.tigre_de_tazmania,R.drawable.bandicoot, R.drawable.rino,
        R.drawable.tigrecaspio

};
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
imageView.setTag(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;

gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, laActivityDetalle.class);
        i.putExtra("imagenSeleccionada",(Integer)v.getTag());
        startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Intenta esto
Cambias todo de esta manera y en tu activity donde quieres agarrar la imagen, pones un ImageView y al imageView le vas a poner el resource tomando el int del Extra que mandaste.